# What is wrong with my comparator?

Tags: java, int, comparator

I am trying to sort Employees based on Age, (simplified example) but I can't get my unit test to work.

```
public class Employee{

    private int age;    

    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age=age;    
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return this.age;    
    }
}
```

My comparator look like the following:

```
class AgeComparator implements Comparator<Employee>{

    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2){

        int emp1Age = emp1.getAge();        
        int emp2Age = emp2.getAge();

        if(emp1Age > emp2Age)
            return 1;
        else if(emp1Age < emp2Age)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;    
    }
}
```

And my unit test:

```
public class AgeComparatorTest {

    @Test
    public void testAge(){
        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        e1.setAge(4);

        Employee e2 = new Employee();
        e2.setAge(7);

        List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        employeeList.add(e1);
        employeeList.add(e2);

        Collections.sort(employeeList, new AgeComparator());
        Employee actual = employeeList.get(0);

        Assert.assertEquals(e2.getAge(), actual.getAge());

    }
}
```

And I am expecting the employee with age 7 to be before 4 but I get.

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<7> but was:<4>

Comment: It's not `compareTo`, @user1329572. This is a `Comparator`, not `Comparable`.

Answer (score 3):

You sort them in ascending order, so this is exactly the expected behaviour of your code.

Note that you can simplify your `Comparator` like this to get the behaviour you want, you don't have to return exactly `-1/1`, any positive or negative `int` will do.
**[EDIT]**
As @JBNizet points out in a comment, simply returning `emp2.getAge() - emp1.getAge()` in comparators can potentially overflow for big values. It is much better to for example use the `Guava` `Ints.compare()` method:

```
class AgeComparator implements Comparator<Employee>{
    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2){
        return Ints.compare(emp2.getAge(), emp1.getAge());
    }
}
```

Comment: This works only for small integers. For very large ones, it can overflow and give incorrect results. I like using Guava's `Ints.compare(i1, i2)` for this.

Comment: Excellent point, @JBNizet! It didn't cross my mind and it's just about the kind of problem that can cause the subtlest of bugs. Sure, in this case, if we aren't dealing with elves or something, this will work as intended.

Comment: @JBNizet: Good point. However, for a field named `age` this will probably not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I see my mistake now, after staring at the code for a couple of hours one seem to miss the obvious.

Comment: Bad habits (that I've had in the past as well) tend to spread, and unless there is a big red warning "beware, this works only because ages are small", someone *will* copy'n paste this code and use it where it should not be used. I would use correct code from the beginning. It's not as if reimplementing `Ints.compare()` as the OP did was difficult.

Comment: @JBNizet: I agree on all accounts. Edited to add your improvement.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your comparator.  It's just that you chose to arrange items in ascending order.

I suggest you look at [Guava Ordering](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) class.  It has a very convenient method `reverse`.

If you have ascending Comparator, it makes it very simple to produce descending comparator implemented in terms of your ascending one.

If you want to fix your comparator for descending sort, just switch variable names in declaration and leave the logic the same, e.g.

```
public int compare(Employee emp2, Employee emp1){
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.utils.Collections` sorts the specified list into **ascending** order, so the first employee in list is of age 4.

Answer (score 0):

Change the if condition and invert your comparison conditions! Natural sorting follows small to high whereas you want a high to low order